# What is a Visual Studio TypeScript Virtual Project? And how can I get it out of my way if I'm compiling externally?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, webpack

The first part of this question is the most important. There are a lot of stack questions around Visual Studio and TypeScript and "TypeScript Virtual Projects" but I have found nothing that explains what TypeScript Virtual Projects are, what they do for me, and what to do when they are "in the way". I have never found any official documentation on this from Microsoft so it would be great if someone from that team or close to the team could respond. "TypeScript Virtual Projects" have remained in VS 2017 and I am seeing the same problems as in VS 2015.

Second part of the question...I am trying to use Visual Studio 2015 with an Angular 2 and TypeScript app but I am using Webpack as an external TS compiler and build.  For the most part it works but every now and then the TypeScript Virtual Projects gives errors in the output window and in the code even though I can successfully compile. Most of them are not being able to find the @angular/core imports etc. What is confusing is that the TS Virtual Project sometimes catches real errors also.  So do I need Virtual Project for intellisense and compile checking?

My current state is that I am doing 2 compiles to try to keep TypeScript Virtual Project happy, even thought sometimes it still complains. The first build is using tsc as part of VS build but then I do my normal Webpack build with SourceMaps for debugging. This seems to work 90% of the time but the other 10% when TS Virtual Project gets in the way is so frustrating and since they are still in Visual Studio 2017 it's important to know what's going on.

The ultimate goal is to be able to use Visual Studio as my editor and debugger (with all it's great features) with intellisense and compile checking but to use an external TypeScript build like Webpack for building/bundling etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to **tsconfig.json** next option helped me:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "watch": true,
    ...
```

And don't forget to add

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

to any `<PropertyGroup>` your project file.